# Calling an overloaded function from a derived class.

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm trying to compile next code in Visual Studio 2010:

```
A {
public:
  void f(int i) {cout << i;}
};

class B: public A {
public:
  void f(string s) {cout << s;}
};

void main() {
  A a;
  B b;

  a.f(1);
  b.f("zazaza");
  b.f(1); //Compilation fail
}
```

But compilation fails. I cannot understand why I cannot call f(int) from parent class. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Is it because A's `f` is not virtual?

Comment: f(string) is hiding f(int)

Comment: @Ben : f shouldn't be virtual, noone override it...

Comment: What you are trying to do has really nothing to do with polymorphism. Polymorphism is used when working with pointers and references in order to treat objects of the same hierarchy in the same way.

Comment: @Veritas , I mean ad-hoc polymorphism [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism) But yes, overloading is more common.

Comment: @user3555886 Point taken. In the standard polymorphism refers to run-time polymorphism using virtual-dispatch. It's also what most people mean so I thought it would be a good idea to point this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `void f(string);` in the derived class is hiding the parent's same name method, not overriding it. You can use `using` keyword in the derived class to un-hide it.

```
class B: public A
{
public:

    using A::f;
    //^^^^^^^^^

    void f(string s)
    {
        cout << s;
    }
};
```

*Now, both two `f` methods are overloads to each other and the `f(int)` is avaiable.*

Answer (score 4):

The `f(int i)` in class `A` gets hidden when you define another method in `B` with the same name.  That's why `A::f(int i)` can be called with `A` object, but not with `B` object. If you want to [**overlaod**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), both of the methods should be in same class with *different method signature*. If you want to [**override**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding), the base class method will be declared as `virtual`, and the method signature *must be same*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I rely on IntellySense and it shows both variants of function.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are performing [Method Hiding](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/35681/), but not [Method Overriding](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/47505/).
As others have suggested, you need to keep an *overload* and *virtual* method in Parent class *(void f(string);)*, so that you may override it.